# Ruby gems to find details about music

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, rubygems

I want to build an app related to musics.

Can someone please suggest me some ruby gems that can help me in finding music ratings/finding top musics of particular band or singer.

Answer (score 0):

go http://rubygems.org/

type music

You'll see that there are many music related gems. However if you are building an app that finds top rated music, I suggest looking into the APIs for various music services, check Rdio, Spotify, Soundcloud, Groovshark etc. I believe most of those have fairly complete APIs that will allow you to access the kind information you might be looking for.

Comment: I tried it but I didn't find any interesting gem, which is easy to use.

Comment: most of the gems im aware of relating to music are midi libraries etc. Like I said, it sounds more like you need to find the right API and then build out the rating feature.